# How can I list the functions in the current file in vim

Tags: vim

I'm new to vim and wanted to know how I can list all functions inside the current file within vim.

Answer (score 21):

> How can I list *anything* in the current file in vim?

The most basic command for listing all lines matching a pattern is `:help :global`:

```
:g/foo      " if you have line numbers enabled
:g/foo/#    " if you don't
```

So, to list functions (declared with the keyword `function`) you would do something like `:g/^func`:

[image: :g/^func]

and then `:78<CR>` to jump to `qf#GetList()`.

Comment: Great, is there a way to scroll through and go to one of these functions. Similar to fuzzy searching/opening files with Ctrl+P

Comment: How to use that list is already explained in the answer and, if you already use it, there are CtrlP extensions that do just that.

Comment: The `..^func` doesn't provide functionality to scroll and select to go to the function so it wasn't actually explained in the answer. For future readers `CtrlPBufTag` will provide this.

Comment: How to use that list is explained: no scrolling/selecting needed.

Comment: What about C++ functions?

Comment: @Fractale, yes?

Comment: There is no function keyword. It's just typename functionname (param)

Comment: @Fractale, then you would need a much more complex pattern (meh) or a something tailored for C++ (yay).

Comment: Vim in not able to "understand" what is what? I'm surprised as it's able to indent and color things properly

Comment: Vim is dumb as a rock. It doesn't understand anything related to code but it has primitive tricks up its sleeve that all more or less depend on regular expressions and kind of give the illusion of some intelligence.

Comment: nice theme. how its called?

Comment: @alexzander, Thanks, [I eat my own dog food](https://github.com/romainl/Apprentice).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:  I mapped to Ctrl-f  (list functions) but you can map to any key you like
Press Ctrl-f will list the functions.  Then issue ":"line_no

Comment: " nnoremap <C-f> :g/^\S\+.*(.*\()\\|\n.*)\)\(.*{\\|\n.*{\)/#<CR> "

Answer (score 2):

A little late to the party, stumbled across this looking for something else... But to get a populated location list that you can "scroll" up and down on, as OP, asked in a comment to an answer:

```
function! Matches(pat)
    let buffer=bufnr("") "current buffer number
    let b:lines=[]
    execute ":%g/" . a:pat . "/let b:lines+=[{'bufnr':" . 'buffer' . ", 'lnum':" . "line('.')" . ", 'text': escape(getline('.'),'\"')}]"
    call setloclist(0, [], ' ', {'items': b:lines})
    lopen
endfunction

call Matches('^\(\s*\)\=function!\=.*(.*)\( abort\)\=$')
```

So the Matches function takes a regex and searches for it, then populates a location list and opens it.

So...

```
call Matches(@/)
```

would then just populate a list for the last search.

The regex example above takes into account:

```
function name()
function! name()
function name() abort
function! name() abort
```

I've probably missed some combinations but give it ago.

Comment: I think with very magic would be more readable `call Matches('\v^(\s*)?fun(ction)?!+.*(.*)( abort)?$')`  and sometimes people define functions abreviated, so `fun(ction)?`.

Comment: Once we are working in a local list, I came up with a little question: How to jump to the next item with no need to jump to the location list. And the vim help system came in handy: We can use   `:ll 3`   to jump to the third match
or `:lne[xt] :lp[revious]  :lr[ewin] :lla[st]`

To reopen the local list use:  `:lf[file]`

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Vim is a (powerful) text editor, not an IDE. So, the basics start with simple *text searches* for a pattern that matches all function definitions (depending on your programming language), e.g. done with `:global/^def/print`. If the syntax performs *folding* of functions (many syntaxes do, or can be configured to), you can close all folds to get this overview.

Then, Vim integrates with `:help tags`. There are plugins that analyze the current file and display all functions, properties, etc. in a sidebar; this is already quite similar to what IDEs offer:

- [taglist plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273)
- [tagbar plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3465)

Comment: @milaniez: `:TlistToggle` opens a sidebar that lists all functions from the current buffer (often sorted by class / method / ..., depending on the language).